# Its safe to use ThreadLocal on OSGi?

Tags: security, osgi

I'm developing an OSGi based system that provides a web application using the HTTP Service spec.

I'm investigating alternatives to safely hold authenticated user data.
The common practice in Java EE is to use a ThreadContext object that is saved in a ThreadLocal map.

Is this approach safe to use in an OSGi container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OSGi is completely moot on what you do with your threads so in general ThreadLocal works as expected. However, realize that it also means that there are multiple threads visible to your application.

You might want to take a look the OSGi Coordinator specification that provides a standardized way for sharing data on a call chain.

Comment: This might be a little late, but let me ask still. Is there a way for two bundles to communicate/use the same ThreadLocal variable? Since as far as I know, two different classloader for each bundle will have two separate ThreadLocal instances.

Comment: No, ThreadLocal is a class from the JVM library and is therefore shared between all bundles.

Answer (score 1):

Peter's answer about ThreadLocal in OSGi is correct, but there are easier solutions to work with user authentication.

Take a look at [Amdatu Security](http://amdatu.org/components/security.html), this offers an OSGi service that takes care of storing user tokens that can be set in a cookie. The default implementation uses MongoDB for the actual token storage, but other implementations can be plugged in easily. Also don't forget that by storing this kind of data in-memory, it becomes harder to implement horizontal scaling.